# Syntax to load wkt or (x,y) formatted geometry from .csv files on PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, csv, file-formats, vector-layer

I'm trying to load some points through a vectorlayer on my QMainWindow, part of my pyqgis application. The code is:

```
    uri = 'file:///C:/Users/.../data/Targets_com.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=x&yField=y'
    # uri = 'file:///C:/Users/.../data/Targets_wkt.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326'#&wktField=wkt'
    # Loading the layer and check it:
    self.target_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Targets' , 'delimitedtext')
    if self.target_layer.isValid():
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.target_layer)
        print('Layer OKKK')
    else:
        print('Layer Fail')
    self.target_layer.updateExtents()
```

When I run my application with that, I get "Layer Fail", so for sure there is something wrong in my "uri" definition, isn't it?

If I change uri like:

```
uri = 'file:///C:/Users/.../data/Targets_com.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326'
```

that is, cutting the geometry definition (on both cases: (x,y) and wkt), I get the "Layer OKKK", but I can't see my points on the map.

I think the .csv files are well written, cause I can load them on QGIS. Anyway, this are my files.csv (and I tried with one more using ";" like delimiter):

[image]
I have read all the posts I found about csv files and syntax with qgis, but I don't know how to solve this, anyone have any idea? i'm using the OSGeo4W package (QGIS 2.16, its own python interpreter, PyQt4,...) and using eclipse-PyDev for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following for your X,Y data format:

```
uri = "file:///C:/Users/.../data/Targets_com.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "LON", "LAT")
```

where you can specify the field names at the end.

---

The following worked for me from the **Python Console**:

```
uri = "file:///C:/Users/.../data/Targets_com.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "LON", "LAT")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Point example', "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Wou, thank you, I already tried to specify fields at the end. My fault was that the names were incorrect: (",", "x", "y") instead of (",", "LON", "LAT")...

Comment: @NachoF. - Most welcome and don't worry, that is a very easy mistake to make ;)